# Dimension of given subspace $P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How do I find the dimension of $H = \{(a+b) + bt + (a-2b)t^2\} \subset P_2$ , where $a, b \in \Bbb R$?

How do I solve this with a matrix? Can I lay it out in matrix form and solve?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the standard basis $(1,t,t^2)$ of $P_2$, you are looking at vectors of the form $(a+b,b,a-2b) = a(1,0,1) + b(1,1,-2)$. In other words, your subspace is the span of the vectors $(1,0,1)$ and $(1,1,-2)$. Are these linearly independent? If this is the case, then your subspace must have dimension $2$.